# Using PHP's preg_match_all to extract a URL

Tags: php, regex, url

I have been struggling for a while now to make the following work. Basically, I'd like to be able to extract a URL from an expression contained in an HTML template, as follows:

```
{rssfeed:url(http://www.example.com/feeds/posts/default)}
```

The idea is that, when this is found, the URL is extracted, and an RSS feed parser is used to get the RSS and insert it here. It all works, for example, if I hardcode the URL in my PHP code, but I just need to get this regex figured out so the template is actually flexible enough to be useful in many situations.

I've tried at least ten different regex expressions, mostly found here on SO, but none are working. The regex doesn't even need to validate the URL; I just want to find it and extract it, and the delimiters for the URL don't need to be parens, either.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/\{rssfeed\:url\(([^)]*)\)\}/`

```
preg_match_all('/\{rssfeed\:url\(([^)]*)\)\}/', '{rssfeed:url(http://www.example.com/feeds/posts/default)}', $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

you should be able to get ALL the urls on the content available in `$matches[1]`..

Note: this will only get urls with the `{rssfeed:url()}` format, not all the urls in the content.

you can try this here: http://www.spaweditor.com/scripts/regex/index.php

Comment: Thank you very much for this simple solution, and thank you also for the link to that online regex testing tool -- very nice and handy!

Comment: been using it for a while now. hope it helped. although it wouldnt verify if the url is valid or not. assuming that the urls are valid that regex should be safe.

Answer (score 4):

Could this work for you?

```
'@((https?://)?([-\w]+\.[-\w\.]+)+\w(:\d+)?(/([-\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)*)@'
```

I use it to match URLs in text.

**Example:**

```
$subject = "{rssfeed:url(http://www.example.com/feeds/posts/default)}";
$pattern ='@((https?://)?([-\w]+\.[-\w\.]+)+\w(:\d+)?(/([-\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)*)@';    
preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches);

print($matches[1][0]);
```

**Output:**

```
http://www.example.com/feeds/posts/default
```

**Note:**

There is also a nice article on Daring Fireball called [An Improved Liberal, Accurate Regex Pattern for Matching URLs](http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls) that could be interesting for you.

Comment: He can probably select everything inside `url(..)`. The RSS feed _should_ have valid URLs

Comment: @Ejay Yes. However, the code provided works in a more general fashion. In the future, KenBoyer may want to retrieve other URLs, not located between `url(` and `)`. However, I can provide the code for that too, if required.

Comment: Thank you very much, though I decided to go with the simpler answer below. I will, however, keep yours in mind if I need to do more sophisticated things in the future.

Comment: @KenBoyer You're welcome. That's how it works. Mark the answer that suits you best. Meanwhile, I'll leave mine so it can help others. :)

Comment: @Jean your code provides some nice regexp for _validating URLs_ as well :) That's useful.